# Spring Boot Scheduled Annotation Job Issue

Tags: spring-boot, sql-server-2008, hikaricp

I am using **spring boot 2.x with hikari CP** as data source and **MSSQL** as database.There are 4 @scheduled Job which runs at 5 seconds fixed delay.
There is one @scheduled Job that Execute one SQL query and get the result by **jdbcTemplate.queryForList.** Some times this query does not return the response(As per the logs).
When i checked the logs, i found no logs printed after query and stuck at jdbcTemplate.queryForList and the thread (suppose scheduled-thread 1) was assigned to this has been assigned to another scheduled Task even this has not been completed.
Because of this that scheduled task has not been completed and also this Task is not executing anymore. When i restart the service this job start again.
Ideally if query takes long time it should throw some exception like timeout or any other exception so that this job completed and can be started again after 5 second.
I am not getting how a thread assigned to some other thread job if assigned task not completed.

Please help me here.
Thanks

Comment: What is your question here? You don't ask anything.

Comment: Sorry if i am not clear. Firstly my problem is that One of my schedule job not executing completely means stuck at db query, and in logs i am not seeing any exception and it never start again until i restart the service(even it is scheduled to run every 5 sec). I hope my problem statement is clear.

Comment: Hi Team, Please let me know, it's little bit urgent, though i have another solution for this, but actually need to know about this strange behavior of Scheduled job of spring boot.I have not found any clue for this over the internet. I have tried to implement query time out also, but it's also not working.

Comment: 1. The users here are not a "team", we are (unpaid) volunteers. 2. [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) TL;DR: Never. If a matter is urgent, then you need to hire a consultant

Comment: No problem issue resolved as it was db lock issue which was causing this schedular to halt